# UML model to Web Service

Tags: web-services, uml

What better form to develop a UML model to web service?

I am beginning  a new project and a need build a UML model to web service.

Comment: This is an opinion based question

Comment: Any UML diagram may be useful. See [uml-diagrams.org: UML Diagrams Examples](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html) for some inspiration

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of profiles available (Google is your friend: "uml profile for web services"). Depending on the tool you use you should use one of those profiles. They offer a couple of stereotyped UML elements that are designed to model web services.